# Terraform count error when condition with variables used

Tags: terraform

Running Terraform 0.12.24 code that was upgraded from 0.11.15 and getting an error related to count on a resource. The count statement has a conditional in it and the line of code and error are:

```
75:   count                  = var.vpc_count == 0 || var.tgw_count == 0 ? 0 : var.vpc_count

The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the count depends on.
```

Both of the variables are simple numbers, either 0 or 1 and are in the tfvars file and passed into the module.

I have searched but couldn't find anything related to this error when the count has simple variables and a conditional in it.

How can I get this to work?

Here is the code inside the module

```
resource "aws_route" "private-1-tgw" {
  provider               = aws.acct
  count                  = "${var.vpc_count}" == 0 || "${var.tgw_count}" == 0 ? 0 : "${var.vpc_count}"
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.private-1[0].id
  destination_cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/8"
  transit_gateway_id     = var.tgw_id
}
```

Here is what is in tfvars file

```
hmi_vpc_count = 1
tgw_count = 0
```

And here is the module call

```
module "hmi-vpc" {
  source = "../../modules/hmi-vpc"

  providers = {
    aws.acct = aws.acct
  }

  aws_account                   = var.aws_account
  aws_region                    = var.aws_region
  management_sg_rules           = var.management_sg_rules
  tgw_count                     = module.transit-gateway.tgw_id == "" ? 0 : var.tgw_count
  tgw_id                        = module.transit-gateway.tgw_id
  tags                          = var.tags
  vpc_cidr                      = var.hmi_vpc_cidr
  vpc_count                     = var.hmi_vpc_count
  vpc_dhcp_count                = var.hmi_vpc_dhcp_count
  vpc_dhcp_domain_name          = var.hmi_vpc_dhcp_domain_name
  vpc_dhcp_dns_servers          = var.hmi_vpc_dhcp_dns_servers
  vpc_dhcp_netbios_name_servers = var.hmi_vpc_dhcp_netbios_name_servers
  vpc_dhcp_ntp_servers          = var.hmi_vpc_dhcp_ntp_servers
  vpc_sn_private_1a_cidr        = var.hmi_vpc_sn_private_1a_cidr
  vpc_sn_private_1b_cidr        = var.hmi_vpc_sn_private_1b_cidr
  vpc_sn_private_1c_cidr        = var.hmi_vpc_sn_private_1c_cidr
  vpc_sn_public_1a_cidr         = var.hmi_vpc_sn_public_1a_cidr
  vpc_sn_public_1b_cidr         = var.hmi_vpc_sn_public_1b_cidr
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Terraform code as a [mcve] please?

Comment: Sure, thought the one line in the error was enough but my bad. Added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the line (in `module "hmi-vpc" { ... }`)

```
  tgw_count = module.transit-gateway.tgw_id == "" ? 0 : var.tgw_count
```

which depends on the execution of the `module.transit-gateway`. To resolve this you should think about a condition that does not depend on an output of the module but maybe on an input variable of it. e.g.:

```
  tgw_count = var.tgw_disabled ? 0 : var.tgw_count
```

or based on the information provided even

```
  tgw_count = var.tgw_count
```

might work for you.

Comment: I think you just pointed out a whopping case of overthinking something in code. You are right the the tgw_count variable would either be set to 1 or zero based on if there was a tgw or not. So evaluating if the ID is blank or not is unnecessary since the variable would be consistent with the intent. Will test it out to verify and let you know.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion was correct. Marking this a solved.